# trying to put JSONObject inside @Field in POST Api but not working

Tags: android, post, kotlin, retrofit2

```
  @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @POST("/api/v1/search/filter")
    @FormUrlEncoded fun searchFilter(@Field("leaf_id") leaf_id: Int,
                                     @Field("lang") lang: String,
                                     @Field("token") token: String,
                                     @Field("ud_id") ud_id: String,
                                     @Field("min_price") min_price: Float,
                                     @Field("max") max: Float,
                                     @Field("page") page: Int,
                                     @Field("per_page") per_page: Int,
                                     @Field("properties") properties:JSONObject): Observable<RespProductsInCatg>
```

here in the `@Field("properties")` I'm trying to send json object but getting failed response.
In Postman its returning proper response

Comment: Did you try in POSTMAN, is it running properly there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a data class for parameters to be passed in properties field.
Then pass an object of that data class, and use @Body instead of @Field for properties.

Comment: i need to add JsonObject named "properties" in my request, how do i do that?

Comment: something like this {
    "Марка" : [
      "ЭУД 72700"
    ]
  }

Comment: Just create a kt file like Request model.kt

Comment: Then use data class Properties(

Comment: Hi, I've done something similar to this.Hipe you understand the code.data class ResponseResult(
        var responses: ArrayList<ResponseList>
)

data class ResponseList(
        var question: Int = 0,
        var response: Int = 0
)

Comment: Pass an object of type ResponseResult as in above using @Body request:ResponseResult

Comment: considering that i'm creating json from HashMap<String, Array<String>>  i cannot know what kind of parameters can be inside HashMap

Comment: with @Body i have to remove all the @Field*s from my request and leave like searchFilter(@Body request)  right?

Comment: No you just have to add @Body for properties.It worked for me.You can leave the rest as it is.

Comment: the type of the @Body should be ResponseResult right? is it data class of properties?

Comment: can i pass json string of properties to @Body?

Comment: Yes,it was easier than creating a hashmap, for me

Comment: mm, but for my case i don't have choice but HashMap i guess

Comment: You do not need to convert to JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Try creating whole request as an object and add the same as @Body param without using @Field values.

Something like

```
data class Request(var leaf_id:Int,
               var lang: String,
               .
               .
               .
               var properties: List<Property>);
```

and

```
 data class Property(var param1:Int, .... );
```

construct the Request Object and try adding just that as @Body param.